# How to achieve Quorum consistency if Local datacenter is down in Cassandra?

Tags: java, cassandra, nosql, cassandra-3.0

I have 3 dc's with 3 nodes each and replication factor is 3.

lets say dc's to be:
x - 3,
y - 3,
z - 3
so total 9 replication factor. to achieve quorum at any given point of time 5 should be up.

x is my local datacenter and let's say x is completely down so basically 3 nodes are down.

according to quorum consistency definition if y and z are up it becomes 3+3=6 replication factor so quorum should be achieved.

My setting for the connecting to cassandra is this:

```
DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy dcAwareRoundRobinPolicy = DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy
                                                    .builder()
                                                    .withLocalDc("x")
                                                    .withUsedHostsPerRemoteDc(3)
                                                    .build();
    Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder()
            .withSocketOptions(getOptions()).addContactPoints(getCassandraHost())
            .withCredentials("casssandra","cassandra")
            .withQueryOptions(new QueryOptions().setConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.QUORUM))
            .withLoadBalancingPolicy(new TokenAwarePolicy(dcAwareRoundRobinPolicy))
            .build();
```

I get no host available exception with the host of x being mentioned. It never tries to connect to remote host to achieve quorum consistency.

what settings I am missing?

I don't want to use .allowRemoteDCsForLocalConsistencyLevel() as I have a fall back from Local_quorum to Quorum so if I use .allowRemoteDCsForLocalConsistencyLevel() my local_quorum will automatically fall back to remote dc.

Comment: Something else is going wrong, what initial nodes are you connecting to on the client? `NoHostsAvailable` doesn't mean you're not achieving consistency, it means the client cannot connect to C* at all. `UnavailableException` would be what you'd see if you're not  achieving the desired consistency. [Solid article on this](https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/cassandra-error-handling-done-right).

Comment: you are correct.. It connects well if x datacenter is up but if I bring x down completely then it throws noHostsAvailable.. one more observation here, If I have one node of x datacenter up then it achieves QUORUM consistency.. I am trying to test when there is an outage to datacenter X how to connect to cassandra and achieve QUORUM consistency..

Comment: I am connecting to all the nodes of datacenter x,y and z..

Comment: @LyubenTodorov were you able to find any answer on this?

Comment: From what you're saying it sounds like a networking problem whereby you can connect to DC "X" but not the other DCs.